# AdMob no show Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, admob

I have two phones, one with 2.3.6 and other with 3.4.0.
¿Why a cant see admob at 2.3.6 ?
I have no problems with the other.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

dependencies

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

defaultConfig

```
applicationId "NAME.NAME"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.4"
```

dependencies

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
```

AND

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Were is the problem??
Thanks

Comment: What is your target and minimum API @Juan

Comment: minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may not be any problem. Have a look at your log.

It could just be that there is no ad available for one due to some filtering rule at the server end, perhaps based upon Android version or randomness.